# AngularJS doesn't bind ng-model to scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I have the following code for my search function

```
<ion-content class="has-header" id="content" push-search>
  <div id="search-bar">
   <div class="item item-input-inset">
     <label class="item-input-wrapper" id="search-input">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()">
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div>
   <// code for displaying search results//>
</ion-content>
```

Search Controller

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, SearchFactory) {
  var doSearch = ionic.debounce(function(query) {
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.results = SearchFactory.get({'query':$scope.query});
  }, 500);
  $scope.search = function() {
    doSearch($scope.query);
  }
})
```

Search Factory:

```
.factory('SearchFactory', function($resource) {
   return $resource(url.concat('/paths/search/:query'), 
                   {query: '@query' } ,
                   { get: { method: 'GET' , isArray: true} }
           );

})
```

When I do call Search, there is no $scope.query in my $scope:
 (see) https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuxRt.png

Comment: What happens when you initialize it to an empty string at the top of your controller?

Comment: @Blazemonger the field $scope.query appears, but remains empty even if there are changes in the search text field. see: http://i.imgur.com/qz46PK3.png

Comment: A [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) would be more helpful to us.

Comment: The code is too complex to refactor into single files for plunkr

Comment: Then do some work to isolate the problem. As it is, I can't even be certain the controller applies to your HTML fragment. It's hard to help you if we can't reproduce the error.

Comment: You don't appear to be using the `query` argument passed into `doSearch`.

Comment: Here is a plunkr of the work I have done so far http://plnkr.co/edit/3IECH5Mmjbjx3q8WH4sZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was solved. See this Link for more info  http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Confirmed this solves it if Angular models aren't working in Ionic

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that the "query" needs to be a field in a scope search object so that it is passed by reference rather than by value, eg:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, SearchFactory) {
  $scope.searchParams = {};
  $scope.searchParams.query = '';

  var doSearch = ionic.debounce(function(query) {
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.results =SearchFactory.get({'query':$scope.searchParams.query});
  }, 500);
```